# x-csrf-tokens with Retrofit API

Tags: android, retrofit2, csrf

I am calling POST API using retrofit in android which requires Authentication and x-csrf-token.
For that I have added below headers :

```
 Request.Builder requestBuilder = original.newBuilder().header("Authorization", basic);
 requestBuilder.header("Accept", "application/json");

  if (!Prefs.with().getString(ApiParamConstant.CSRF_TOKEN, "").isEmpty()) {
     requestBuilder.header("Cookie", "X-CSRF-TOKEN="  + 
     Prefs.with().getString(ApiParamConstant.CSRF_TOKEN, ""));
 }
```

But its throwing retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.HttpException: HTTP 403 Forbidden

Comment: What method of CSRF prevention is being employed by the API? Are you certain that it only requires the Cookie value to be set? If so, try to ensure that CSRF is the issue here, a `403` seems an unusual response for a CSRF failure, but then APIs are all over the place with their return codes...